# Is the union of two locally closed sets in real line, locally closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

**Formal Definition:** A locally closed set in a toplogical space, is an intersection of an open and a closed set.

**My Definition**: A locally open set in a toplogical space, is a union of an open and a closed set.

in complex plane I can find a locally open set which is not locally closed. I couldn't find an example in real line.

Are all locally open sets in $\mathbf{R}$ locally closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A = \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1})$.  This is locally open since $\{0\}$ is closed and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1})$ is open.  Suppose $A$ is locally closed, so $A = U \cap C$ where $U$ is open and $C$ is closed.  Since
$0 \in A \subseteq U$, $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subseteq U$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.
Now if $2^{-n} < \epsilon$, $2^{-n} \in U \backslash A$ so $2^{-n} \notin C$.  But 
$2^{-n} +s \in C$ for $|s|>0$ sufficiently small, contradicting the statement that $C$ is closed.

Comment: great counterexample.